# Glob patterns in bash scripts

Tags: bash, glob

I'm writing a bash script to link some dotfiles from `~/.dotfiles` to `~`.

My entire script is here:

```
declare -a dotfiles=(
    bashrc
    git/.gitconfig
    extra/*
)

for dotfile in "${dotfiles[@]}"; do

    orig_df="$HOME/.dotfiles/$dotfile"
    home_df="null"

    # Add a dot before the name of the file if it hasn't one already
    if [[ `basename "$orig_df"` == .* ]]; then
        home_df="$HOME/`basename $dotfile`"
    else
        home_df="$HOME/.`basename $dotfile`"
    fi

    # Link
    ln -s "$orig_df" "$home_df"
done
```

Everything works except (guess what) the globbing in `extra/*`.

How can I expand it? As by now, it creates a link like this:

```
~/.*  # linked to -> ~/.dotfiles/extra/*
```

(because I told it to prefix a dot when there isn't one already).

Comment: The wildcard should be expanded when you assign the variable, unless it doesn't match anything.

Comment: What variable? `dotfiles` or `orig_df`? Because when it sees `dotfiles` for the first time it doesn't know what `extra/` directory I'm talking about.

Comment: `extra/*` will be expanded relative to the current directory when you assign `dotfiles`, because you didn't put the glob in quotes. If you omit the quotes in the assignment to `orig_df`, it will expand the wildcard then.